# nhibernate get all values for a type

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, type-conversion

I am using NHibernate in my project and I need to get all of the values in a table for a specific type (of domain model) and the type is variable.

I can use the criteria to do criteria.List() but the problem is that the type is variable and passed to me at run time so I need to be able to specify a type that is not constant and get all of the values in that table according to the NHibernate mappings.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try one of the following:

```
session.CreateCriteria(type).List(results);

session.CreateQuery("from " + type.Name).List(results);
```